# Unable to navigate to home page from UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uialertview

I am using a `UITableView` to show data, and by using customise button and delete function I am trying to delete selected row. But i want to put an alertview inside that function when `UITableView` is empty, and by using buttons inside the `UIAlertView` I am trying to navigate to main page and previous page according to conditions. But it's getting crashed after `UITableView` is getting empty and I push the delete button with "Program received signal:  “SIGABRT".

My code looks like this:

```
    - (IBAction)DeleteButtonAction:(id)sender
    {   
        DMSAppDelegate *d = (DMSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        NSLog(@"Message From Custom Cell Received");

        if(d->newtableData.count != 0)
        {

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tablevieww2 indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[[[sender superview] superview] superview]];
            NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
            [d->newtableDataQt removeObjectAtIndex:row];
            NSLog(@"data removed");
            [self.tablevieww2 reloadData];
        }   
        else
        {       
            UIAlertView *alertview=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"hello" message:@"Warning!!: Table is empty" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:@"",@"No",nil];
            textfieldQty1 = [alertview textFieldAtIndex:0];
            textfieldQty1.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
            textfieldQty1.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
            textfieldQty1.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
            [alertview show];
            [alertview release];    
        }

    }

    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 0) 
        {
            DMSViewController *bt=[[DMSViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
            bt.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
            [self presentModalViewController:bt animated:YES];
        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            NSString *newqty = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",textfieldQty1.text];
            DMSAppDelegate *d= (DMSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            [d->newtableDataQt replaceObjectAtIndex:slCell1 withObject:(id)newqty];
            NSLog(@"tb%@",d->newtableDataQt);
            [self.tablevieww2 reloadData];  
            int total1=0;

            for ( int i=0 ; i < [d->newtableDataQt count];++i )
            {           
                NSString *string = [d->newtableDataQt objectAtIndex:i];

                NSLog(@"string%@",string);

                if ([string isEqualToString:@"0"])
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"newArray%@",d->newtableDataPrice);
                    NSString *strP=[d->tableDataPrice objectAtIndex:i];
                    NSInteger sp=[strP integerValue];
                    NSInteger st=[string integerValue];
                    total1=total1+st*sp;
                    NSLog(@"total1%d",total1);
                }
            }

            NSString *newtotal1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",total1];
            DMSAppDelegate *d2 = (DMSAppDelegate   *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            d2->totalD = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:newtotal1];
        }   
    }

    Please give me some solution. I am trying really hard from yesterday but not getting any success.
    Thanks in advance.
    @
```

Comment: post the crash logs and console statements.

Comment: Where is your delete button, is it outside the table because if the table view is empty so how is your delete button visible and where.

Comment: yes it's outside the tableview in another section footer so my delete button is visible every time. and it's working fine when there is data in tableview but getting crashed when table is empty as I mentioned..

Comment: If `UITableView` is already empty, then how would you select or delete any `row`.

Comment: Can you put the breakpoint in these two methods and debug your code to find where the app is exactly crashing and post the line and console message that why the app is getting crash.

Comment: Try enabling ‘Zombie’. May be its because your tableview is empty and you are trying to access data from it.

Comment: @Gypsa : 
2012-01-07 12:04:27.482 DMS[4958:207] Message From Custom Cell Received
2012-01-07 12:04:28.508 DMS[4958:207] data removed
(gdb) continue
2012-01-07 12:04:40.820 DMS[4958:207] Message From Custom Cell Received
2012-01-07 12:04:43.310 DMS[4958:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.

This is what i am getting.

Comment: @Gypsa: It's not coming to the else part i mentioned in delete button fuction . It's getting crashed at else part. I hope you understand ..

Comment: @Nina: what is "Zombie" and how to enable it ?

Comment: @Fabre NSZombieEnabled to YES in your product - edit scheme - arguments. It indicates the deallocated objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check two things:-

First:- `if(d->newtableData.count != 0)`
is the condition and you are not removing the items from `newtableData` you are removing it from `newtableDataQt` so thats why your else method is not getting called. because `newtableData` will never have count =0.

Second thing;-
one thing if your table is empty means that `newtableDataQt` will contain no values , it will be empty.Now when you click on the delete button, the alert view appears , after that if you click whatever button at index 1 then in your code you have written :-

```
[d->newtableDataQt replaceObjectAtIndex:slCell1 withObject:(id)newqty];
```

so `newtableDataQt` has already be empty before and now you are using it.This might be the reason of crash.

try

```
if( [newtableDataQt count] >slCell1)
{    [d->newtableDataQt replaceObjectAtIndex:slCell1 withObject:(id)newqty];
}
```

I hope it might help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear :) it solved my problem :)I understood why it's crushing ..Thanks :)

Comment: @Fabre U are welcome.Happy Coding.You can upvote the answer too.It motivates people to help more..